# How Do I Resolve Run-Time Error With GetValue Function in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, function, getvalue

I am trying to write a macro that copies data from multiple external workbooks to a single workbook in a certain order. I do not intend to have each workbook be open for my macro to work, as that would be an outrageous number of open spreadsheets, so I did a Google search and came across this nifty function, the GetValue function:
http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/

Just to set myself up for the rest of the code, I made a code that is supposed to simply take a single piece of data from a cell of an external workbook, and put it in a single cell of the workbook and sheet I'm currently in. In the current worksheet, I stuck the file paths of the workbooks I want access into the B column, and the file names in the A column, since there are so many and I want to be able to access each in a single code. Here is that code:

```
Sub Gather_Data()

Dim p As String
Dim f As String
Dim s As String
Dim a As String

p = Range("B7").Value
f = Range("A7").Value
s = Sheet5
a = D7

Cells(10, 10).Value = GetValue(p, f, s, a).Value

End Sub

Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
'   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code, but whenever I try to run it I get a run-time error that states, "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed". I honestly have no idea what that means and running the debugger highlights the

```
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

area, which I didn't even write. If anyone has experience using this function or knows how to resolve this error, your input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are declared as String, so try changing your code from this:

```
s = Sheet5
a = D7
```

To this:

```
s = "Sheet5"
a = "D7"
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have been able to sniff that out myself...oops.